# Expect a function but a value is passed

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have following trait definition:

```
trait Printable[A] { self =>
  def format(value: A): String

  def show() : String = "Hello"

  def contramap[B](func: B => A): Printable[B] =
    new Printable[B] {
      def format(value: B): String =
        self.format(func(value))
    }
}
```

and a type:

```
final case class Box[A](value: A)
```

and the implicit implementation of it:

```
  implicit def boxPrintable[A](implicit p: Printable[A]) =
    p.contramap[Box[A]](_.value)
```

`contramap` expects a function with `func: B => A` and a value is passing above. Why the compiler does not complain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the underscore.

Remember that `_.value` is shorthand for `x => x.value` which, in this case, means ...

```
(x:Box[A]) => x.value
```

... which fits the definition of `B => A` where `B` is `Box[A]` and `A` is ... well, `A`. It's still unresolved, but the compiler has nothing to complain about because there is nothing contradictory in the code.